# Enrutamiento con htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

tengo un problema al momento de intentar configurar un par de rutas en mi aplicación que no quiero que sigan el hilo principal, pero irremediablemente siempre sigue el hilo principa, esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

DirectoryIndex start.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

IndexIgnore *

RewriteRule ^pan$ pan.php [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ start.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

El objetivo es que todas las solicitudes sean dirigidas a "start.php" salvo las que impliquen "pan" en cuyo caso serán redirigidas a pan.php

pero si o si, siempre van a parar a "start.php", que me estoy perdiendo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible que el problema que estás experimentando esté relacionado con el orden de las reglas RewriteRule en tu archivo .htaccess.

Apache procesa las reglas de reescritura en orden, y utiliza la primera regla que coincide con la solicitud. En tu caso, la regla que redirige a start.php es la última regla, lo que significa que se aplica a todas las solicitudes que no coinciden con las reglas anteriores.

Prueba cambiando el orden de tus reglas RewriteRule para que la regla que redirige a pan.php esté después de la regla que redirige a start.php:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

DirectoryIndex start.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

IndexIgnore *

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ start.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteRule ^pan$ pan.php [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Este cambio debería hacer que Apache redirija las solicitudes a pan.php en lugar de start.php cuando la URL solicitada sea pan.

Otra opción podría ser colocar la regla pan antes de las condiciones de reescritura y la regla start:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

DirectoryIndex start.php

IndexIgnore *

RewriteRule ^pan$ pan.php [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ start.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

</IfModule>
```

Esta última opción debería funcionar ya que la regla para pan se procesa antes que la regla para start y la regla de pan tiene la bandera L que significa que si esta regla se aplica, no se aplicarán más reglas.

Por último, es importante tener en cuenta que cualquier cambio que realices en tu archivo .htaccess puede requerir que reinicies tu servidor Apache para que los cambios surtan efecto.

Comment: Bien .. gracias de antemano porque tu respuesta finalmente me permitió solucionar el asunto. yo siempre tuve entendido que apache tomaría la primera regla que se cumpla y en apariencia así pero aun no estoy claro de porque mi planteamiento inicial no se ejecutaba si la regla relativa a "pan" estaba primero y cerraba  la ejecución a nuevas reglas . pero bueno el orden inverso tampoco me funcionó, sin embargo si lo hizo tu última sugerencia, colocar el redireccionamiento antes de las condiciones.

Comment: Asegúrate de [no utilizar ChatGPT](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5462): está prohibido aquí.